# Flutter upload in background for iOS and Android

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, file-upload, background, firebase-storage

How to upload images to Firebase Storage in the background that means upload continues even the app gets closed?

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: Generally no solution. But I figured it out by saving it on the cache and then uploading it. I saved the cache location URL of the image in Firestore database. Then used a getUrl() function in Firebase function when the upload completes it saves the download URL .